# Which is the best approach for Dependency Injection in Asp.Net MVC 4.0 or later?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

Can anyone explain me when and why we should use **Dependency Injection** ?

and which is the best approach for DI ?

As I searched and found many framework some of them are as below :-

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOf-NETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx

but I'm very confused that which one is the best.

and also what is the difference between IOC and DI ?

anyone here, who can help me ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 6):

## Dependency Injection

Objects in [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) often rely on other objects. That is, classes make references to other classes because they need to use them in order to do their job.

For example, suppose we have a class `Customer`. A `Customer` object is able to retrieve details from a database with a `GetDetails()` method.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {

    }

    public void GetDetails()
    {
        Database db = new Database();

        return db.GetCustomer(this.Id).Details;
    }
}
```

**This is bad.** `Customer` and `Database` are [tightly coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). That means that `Customer` knows too much about `Database`; it's completely dependant on it.

The problem is exacerbated if the `Database` object has more construction requirements.

Imagine this:

```
public void GetDetails()
{
    Database db = new Database("localhost", "3306", "username", "password", "database");

    return db.GetCustomer(this.Id).Details;
}
```

**This is worse.** Now the `Customer` class is doing even more. If every class is creating a `Database` object this gets ugly very quickly. This is hard to maintain and the code breaks if the `Database` class changes. Suppose we no longer need to mention the port in the construction of the object or perhaps we add a few more parameters.

Ultimately, the `Customer` class **shouldn't know so much about the database**. Really, it doesn't care. It just wants to *use* the database.

Let's change our `Customer` to use dependency injection.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private IDatabase db { get; set; }

    public Customer(IDatabase db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public void GetDetails()
    {
        return db.GetCustomer(this.Id).Details;
    }
}
```

This technique is known as constructor injection. We're **injecting** a *dependency* via the **constructor**. Now `Customer` doesn't know what type of database is coming in, how it was created or really anything about it. All `Customer` knows is that it conforms to the `IDatabase` interface and the methods that the interface provides. Great!

## Which DI Container to use?

> but I'm very confused that which one is the best.

For people like you and I, it doesn't really matter. They all do the same thing in slightly different ways. Unless you have a reason for one over the other, pick one that is easy to use, is popular and has plenty of (community) support.

Personally, I use Castle Windsor. I've heard good things about Ninject, Autofac, StructureMap and Unity.

## IoC vs DI

**IoC** means **Inversion of Control**.

**DI** means **Dependency Injection**.

Dependency Injection is one way of implementing Inversion of Control. That is, DI is a technique of IoC.

In our example with a `Customer` class, it was creating and managing a `Database` object. The `Customer` object was **controlling** the `Database` object.

When we implemented dependency injection, we reversed, or **inverted**, that control so that the control of the `Database` was handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

**Why?**

To make (for example) the controller testable.

**How**

Inject all external dependencies (like database-access) via the constructor into the controller.

This priciple is called *Dependency Injection* and you don't really need a container/framework to use it.
Indeed for smallish projects I never do (the overhead is a bit heavy for me) - I just use something like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public MyController ()
        : this(new ActuallImplementationOfDependency())
    {
    }

    public MyController (IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
    // ...
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
but I'm very confused that which one is the best.
```

Well, this is solely depends on the requirements and feasibility of your project. for example, For faster performance Simple injector  is the best, Unity is widely use with MVC while for dynamic proxy one can go for Castle windsor.

You can find entire analysis [here](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison)